# Curl request against PUBBY linked data front end

Tags: curl, rdf

Im trying to get a RDF/XML response but I only get HTML responses.  My curl request is:

```
curl -L -H "Accept: application/rdf+xml" "http://localhost:8080/mydataset/page/def/sector-publico/contrato/cod-centro-destino"
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Trying ::1...
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
GET /mydataset/page/def/sector-publico/contrato/cod-centro-destino HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.53.1
Accept: application/rdf+xml

HTTP/1.1 200
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 4341
Date: Sat, 14 Oct 2017 16:55:21 GMT
```

I have a PUBBY server. What could the problem be?

Comment: Try to add `?output=xml`.

Comment: Dont works, but thank you